# Connecting to a SSH account always asks for passphrase now

Tags: ssh

I'm not sure what happened, but after changing some setting on my macOS Mojave for connecting to GitHub using Sublime Merge, I keep getting a passphrase for key before asking the password for connecting via SSH. (I do know the passphrase as it's the same for my GitHub details)

```
$ ssh username@domain.com
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/user-mac/.ssh/id_rsa': 
username@domain.com's password:
```

It works but I got to enter 2 passwords now (one local and one remote). Is there no way to store the local passphrase securely and saved permanently so that it doesn't ask me again ?

Comment: Try adding your SSH private key to the local SSH agent by running the command: `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. This should ask you for password once but not subsequently.

Comment: Cannot download keys without provider

Comment: What did you change?  Did it have anything to do with `.ssh`?